# Configuring Entity framework/DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've been struggling for quite some time now to inject my context class into my application without any success.

Why does the dbcontext class that I am creating has to be of type generic? Or am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Startup.cs:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Car_proj_new.Models;
    using Microsoft.Data.Entity;


    namespace Car_proj_new
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                Configuration = builder.Build();
            }

            public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }


            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                // Add framework services.

                var connection = Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"];

                services.AddEntityFramework().AddDbContext<CarDbContext>( options => { options.UseSqlServer(connection); });




                services.AddMvc();
            }
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                loggerFactory.AddDebug();

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    app.UseBrowserLink();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                }

                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Db context class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Car_proj_new.Models
{
    public class CarDbContext: DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Corporations> Corporations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PossibleFixes> PossibleFixes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Workers> Workers { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Project.Json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

The error:

Error   CS0311  The type 'Car_proj_new.Models.CarDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.AddDbContext(Action)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Car_proj_new.Models.CarDbContext' to 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext'. Car_proj_new..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

The error seems simple, yet I cannot figure it out, I appreciate your answers.

Comment: Please add your code as text not images

Comment: Maybe you should use System.Data.Entity instead of Microsoft.Data.Entity

Answer (score 0):

With no code here , I can say please check for the following
1) `Name spaces` - If your context class is in a class library , check if the project is added as a reference  (`project.json`)
2) Looks like you are having a reference to EF core - my **guess** but the generated context class is from or uses `full .net framework`

Here is a sample

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(connection); });
```

```js
{
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above works for me . tech stack `.net core` and `EF Core`

Answer (score 0):

add this code into your CarDbContext:

```
namespace Car_proj_new.Models
{
   public class CarDbContext: DbContext
   {
      //***
      public CarDbContext(DbContextOptions<CarDbContext> options) : base (options)
       {
       }
      //***
      public DbSet<Corporations> Corporations { get; set; }
      public DbSet<PossibleFixes> PossibleFixes { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Workers> Workers { get; set; }

   }
}
```